# Odoo: updating related field without changing it's original value

Tags: python, odoo-12

I am trying to update field `price` in model `custom.sale.line` that's related to field `product_id.sell_price` in model `custom.price` but without affecting the original value of the latter (in other way i want the cashier to able to change the value on the sales invoice but without changing the value of the product in the database), i'm wondering if there's any change to do so
I tried making another field `other_price` that takes the value of `price`, but even with `store=True` it doesn't save the new value in the database and reverts to the original value
if anyone have a solution for this problem i would be thankful

below is the code

```
class CustomSaleLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'custom.sale.line'
    _sql_constraints = [
        ('product_br_uniq', 'unique(order_id, product_id)',
         'Cannot add a product that already exists')]
    product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="custom.product", string="Product",
                                 domain="[('branch_line.branch_id.user_lines.user_id','=', user_id)]")
    sell_price = fields.Float(string='Main Price', related='product_id.sell_price', required=True, )
    other_price = fields.Float(string='Other Price', compute='_compute_price', store=True)
store=True, )

    @api.depends('sell_price')
    def _compute_price(self):
        for rec in self:
            rec.other_price = rec.sell_price
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```py
sell_price = fields.Float(string='Main Price', inverse='_compute_dummy', compute='_compute_price', required=True, store=True)

@api.depends('product_id.sell_price')
def _compute_price(self):
    for rec in self:
        rec.sell_price = rec.product_id.sell_price
        
def _compute_dummy(self):
    pass
```